# Can I use css and *ngIF conditions?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

i want to use this

[image]

but the reality

[image]

As for the `css`, do I use `visibility`or is there something else that works?

mycode Html

```
 <div class="col-lg-2" *ngIf="PrhdService.prCheck01"> //<--- this
          <mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="outline">
               <mat-label>date dd/MM/yyyy</mat-label>
               <input matInput name="date" formControlName="date" type="text" required readonly>
               
          </mat-form-field>
     </div>
```

mycode typescript
Should I add something to the function? how?

```
    prCheck01: boolean = false
    prCheck02: boolean = false
    prCheck03: boolean = false
    type!: string

    feedDdataEdit(prno: string) {
      this.PrhdnetworkService.getPr_prhd(prno).subscribe({
      next: data => {
    
      var {  type } = { ...data }
      this.form.setValue({ type})

      this.type=type 

      if (type == '01') {
        this.typeRespones = '01'
        this.prCheck01 = true
        this.prCheck02 = false
        this.prCheck03 = false


      } else if (type == '02') {

        this.typeRespones = '02'
        console.log(this.typeRespones)
        this.prCheck01 = false
        this.prCheck02 = true
        this.prCheck03 = false
    
    } else if (type == '03') {
      this.typeRespones = '03'
      this.prCheck01 = false
      this.prCheck02 = false
      this.prCheck03 = true
    }
```

How can I use them together?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you in this case you could use flex with space-between, but that wouldn't work so well if there is a 4th box and all boxes need to stay in same positions, then i would consider using grids instead, you could also move then ngIf further down into the box and leave the wrapping div recardless of the ngIf

Comment: oh wow it's very easy...but why i can't think.thank

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ng-template>` as place holder and render it only when your *ngIf is falsy.

```
<ng-template #placeHolder>
    <div class="place-holder"></div> 
</ng-template>
```

Now add it after the *ngIf as your "else" statment:

```
<div class="col-lg-2" *ngIf="PrhdService.prCheck01"; else placeHolder>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly (please correct me), but you can use **[NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)** to apply  css classes conditionally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).